# listbox and how to perform actions on selected items

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hi I have this program Im trying to make

but now Im trying to add an option to delete items ( only the selected ones ).

thanx in advance

Comment: what are the symptoms? what is not working about it? Is the average wrong?

Comment: Actually I did the Average it working with me now ... I add the avg code

Comment: I tried this for the delete thing but its not working
listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the selected items:

```
while (listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndices[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = ListBox1.Items.Count -1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for deleting also

Comment: listBox1.Items is an `ObjectCollection`. You're thinking of a `ListView`.

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Selected'